# Linking dynamic library to my project

Tags: c++, makefile

After reading lots of post I am really confused.
I want to link a dynamic library to my cpp code.

The library is  in `/usr/local/include/sbml`
and the libsbml.so file can be found in `/usr/local/lib`

I have a makefile that looks like this

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
VERSION = 5.04.02
CC      = /usr/bin/g++
CFLAGS  = -Wall -g -D_REENTRANT -DVERSION=\"$(VERSION)\"
LDFLAGS = -lsbml

OBJ = main.o SBML.o

prog: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o prog $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm edit $(OBJ)
```

If I run the makefile I get the following error: (undefined reference to SBMLReader::readSBMLFromFile())

```
g++    -c -o SBML.o SBML.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -Wall -g -D_REENTRANT -DVERSION=\"5.04.02\" -o prog main.o SBML.o -lsbml
sbml.o: In Funktion `SBML::readSBML()':
sbml.cpp:(.text+0x129): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `SBMLReader::readSBMLFromFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The Problem is solved. I did a beginners mistake. I installed the library package but I forgot to install the -dev package with all the header files. After installing the second package my makefile works.

Answer (score 3):

The library was not linked because you need to specify the folder containing the so-file as well:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib -lsbml
```

Now it should link and your unresolved symbol should be gone as well.

Comment: ok. I have added this link to an older version of my makefile. It gives me the same error `/usr/bin/g++ -Wall -g -D_REENTRANT -DVERSION=\"5.04.02\" -o prog main.o SBML.o -L/usr/local/lib -lsbml
SBML.o: In Funktion SBML::readSBML():
SBML.cpp:(.text+0x129): Nicht definierter Verweis auf SBMLReader::readSBMLFromFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
` I removed this link because I thought that this folder is in my PATH variable and c++ compiler checks this folder anyway

Comment: Ok, then you should make sure that the used symbol is defined in the version of your lib with the right parameters: nm /usr/local/lib/libsbml.so | grep readSBMLFromFile